# Почему не работает :before:hover

Tags: css, hover

Нужно чтобы когда я наводил мышь на :before (зелёный блок), он менял цвет на синий. А если я наведу мышь на красный блок - ничего не должно произойти.
P.s. конечно, внутрь #block можно поместить ещё один див типа id="before", но мне нужен именно ":before".

```css
#block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;

  background: #f00;
}
#block:before {
  content: "hello";

  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;

  transform: translateX(100%);

  color: #fff;
  background: #0f0;
}

/* не работает */
#block:before:hover {background: #00f}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: потому что `.block:hover::before` надо

Comment: `before` - это _псевдо_ элемент, он не следит за тем, есть над ним кто-то или нет

Comment: На mdn написано, что :hover может применяться к любому псевдоэлементу: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:hover, или я что-то не так понимаю?

А из-за :hover:before, бефор будет становиться синим даже если навести курсор на красный блок (а такого быть не должно).

Comment: это в русской версии mdn написано. в оригинале этого нет. мозилла в инспекторе не дает выставить руками hover для псевдоэлементов.

Comment: @teran, зато такое есть в драфте спецификации :) [The :hover pseudo-class can apply to any pseudo-element.](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#the-hover-pseudo)

Comment: @helloworld, можно поставить `pointer-events: none` для `#block` и `pointer-events: all` для `::before`, тогда сработает `.block:hover::before`